# I Have A Raid 5 Trouble

Tags: raid, raid-5

Hi my Raid is going crazy. I Have a Raid 5 with 4x 3TB Drives and one drive dropped out. So I popped it back in and everything worked Fine But i Had run this and noticed that the Drive was not used.

```
Root@Parkplatz:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : active raid5 sdc[1] sde[3] sdd[2]
      8790405120 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/3] [_UUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

I already added the drive with `mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb` but than the computer crashed. Now I rebooted the computer. I have no Access to my Data and dont know Now to activate my Array again

```
root@Parkplatz:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : inactive sdc[1] sde[3] sdd[2] sdb[4]
      11720542048 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```

I am runing Open media Vault so Debian i think...

Comment: give us more details, how did the computer crash? what OS are you running on?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "going crazy".  If the hdd light is going crazy its probably trying to rebuild/check itself.  Also, you should stop using RAID5 - its unreliable with such a large array.